# Arcane Propulsion Armor — can it give the wearer limbs they never had?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

[Arcane Propulsion Armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/artificer#ArcanePropulsionArmor) can give additional body parts to the wearer instead of "missing" ones:

> If the wearer is missing any limbs, the armor replaces those limbs—hands, arms, feet, legs, or similar appendages. The replacements function identically to the body parts they replace.

An artificer provides such an armor to a naga. Naga has no legs, so it is missing them. Will it get legs from the armor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### No, from context.

In this particular case "missing" means that you [do not have something any more](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/miss_1#miss_1__30). This interpretation is supported by the other verb in the description (emphasis mine):

> If the wearer is missing any limbs, the armor **replaces** those limbs—hands, arms, feet, legs, or similar appendages. The **replacements** function identically to the body parts they **replace**.

Replace means [to take the place of something that was there **before**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/replace): hence, if you had a leg and you lost it during a fight against a Kraken, then Arcane Propulsion Armor can *replace* it with a new one. But since a Naga, as in your example, never had a leg the Arcane Propulsion Armor can not replace it

Comment: Is this scenario possible only when we use the "Lingering Injures" optional rule from the DMG?

Comment: @enkryptor I would say injury house rules are more common. If I knew there was an artificer in my group with this feature I would be likely to have them lose a limb just to give them a use of their cool feature

Comment: @enkryptor No: it sufficient that some enemy creature fighting the party has the [sword of sharpness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/5391-sword-of-sharpness)

Comment: Wouldn't [missing (adjective)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/missing) be a better dictionary reference for this usage, rather than [miss (verb)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/miss_1)? I don't think it would change your answer.

Comment: @smbailey Since the description says *If the wearer is missing any limbs*, the verb miss is used in the passive form: I thought that the verb entry would be the entry mostly on point. But I am not a native speaker, hence I may be mistaking...

Comment: What if the creature used to be human and transformed (willingly or not, permanently or not) into a Naga? If I were DMing I'd rule no legs, but...

Comment: @Blueriver In the form of a Naga, the leg is not missing, since a Naga has no legs at all. Once reverted back,  the creature can't use the armor since it is tailored to be worn by a Naga and not by a human.